# Someone answered a question before it was asked, is this witchcraft?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro

It seems this person asked a question 35 seconds ago, and then went back in time 18 seconds and answered it.

Link: [MySQL on MacOS instaled by brew not working after shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736018/mysql-on-macos-instaled-by-brew-not-working-after-shutdown#44736019)

Image (with freehand ovals below):

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the relevant question?

Comment: Reload the page. The timers are taken care of by JavaScript, and are thus dependent on exactly how fast your page was loaded for them to have started.

Comment: Question link: [MySQL on MacOS instaled by brew not working after shutdown](//stackoverflow.com/q/44736018)

Comment: When you mouse-over the relative times, you'll see that they self-answered, the UTC timestamps match *exactly*. It's just your computer that was slower in starting the relative timers, by 18 seconds apparently.

Comment: Probably Jon Skeet's bot.

Comment: Them ovals though.

Comment: @Ihazkode You mean freehand circles?

Comment: The title is misleading anyway.  Those symptoms could not be caused by a witch or warlock. If anything, you are looking for a Sorcerer or PHP developer.  The cure is beheading and/or burning at the stake.